# Redirect to Route with Multiple Model Objects - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am trying to redirect to a route I have set up in Laravel 4.2, and pass multiple model objects to it.

I have a `search`function in my controller

```
function search()
{
//do search things
 if($type=="sale")
 {
  return Redirect::route('saleSearchResults')->withResults($results); 
 }elseif($type=="rent")
  {
  return Redirect::route('rentSearchResults')->withResults($results);
  }
}
```

The `$results` variable is returned from performing a search query on the database and contains multiple instances of a Listing Model Object. Is there anyway I can pass these results to the routes?

I know I can pass single instances of a model (model binding) as well as individual parameters but I can't seem to pass multiple instances of the model.

The reason I want to do this is because I have one route for searching which goes to my `search` function.

I then want the results of the search to go to different urls depending on the search type.

Search form posts to `/search`

Results for a Sale search are displayed on `/for-sale/search-results/`

Results for a Rent search are disaplayed on `/for-rent/search-results/`

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withResults()` seems to be the right approach to me. It stores the variable in the session for one request and you can retrieve it in the other controller by:

```
$results = Session::get('results');
```

Comment: Ah of course! I didn't try retrieve them with `Session` (for some reason I assumed that wouldn't work!) Problem solved thanks a bunch!